# How to search for multiple criteria across rows in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, search, spreadsheet

Hi (Apologies already if this sounds very complex and is not possible. I appreciate all help),

Below is an example of the first part of my spreadsheet. What I would like to do is input a list of phrases and match them with the spreadsheet values on firstly length, exact _pos, and then the sum of word frequency and lastly, sum of duration. I would like the output this in a separate table, with the matches side by side. Python is the language I feel most comfortable with, but I don't mind any alternatives, if this is possible. Thank you!

[image: My spreadsheet]

Output of print(df.head(10).to_dict('list')):

```
{'subtitle': ['forget', 'it', 'its', 'too', 'risky', 'im', 'through', 'doing', 'that', 'shit'], 'start': [27.0, 27.36, 27.44, 27.56, 27.71, 29.5, 29.58, 29.77, 29.93, 30.07], 'end': [27.36, 27.43, 27.56, 27.71, 28.05, 29.58, 29.77, 29.93, 30.07, 30.27], 'duration': [0.36, 0.07, 0.12, 0.15, 0.34, 0.08, 0.19, 0.16, 0.14, 0.2], 'required': [nan, 0.43, nan, 0.27, nan, 0.42, nan, 0.35, nan, 0.34], 'match': [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], '_pos': ['VBB', 'PNP', 'DPS', 'AV0', 'AJ0', 'NN1', 'PRP', 'VBG', 'DT0', 'NN1'], 'word_freq': [0.000115, 0.00891, 0.00138, 0.000891, 8.71e-06, 4.9e-05, 0.000741, 0.000398, 0.0102, 0.000302], 'required.1': [nan, 0.009025, 0.01029, 0.002271, nan, 5.771e-05, 0.00079, 0.001139, nan, 0.010502], 'start_': [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36], 'end_': [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39]}
```

Comment: Hi @Regan :) Can you give an example of the expected result, please? And can you update your post with the output of `print(df.head(10).to_dict('list'))`

Comment: For the expected result, I would like a table with the matches in one column and the phrase I searched in another column, and both start times and durations columns of these preserved, if possible. I have also updated my post, thank you!